# Traefik docker-compose frontend-rule

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

Using docker-compose (not a swarm mode), how to group docker container in docker-compose.yml to same backend, I'm using this label, under the service in docker-compose.yml

- traefik.enable=true
- traefik.frontend.rule=Host:sub.example.com
- traefik.backend.port=80
- traefik.docker.network=http_network

but when running multiple container,

```
docker-compose --scale service=2
```

it still make multiple frontend and backend(ex:frontend_service_1 to backend_service_1, frontend_service_2 to backend_service_2). Anyone have similar experience and how to make it in one group?

Comment: Did you set traefik to swarm mode? This question is abstract without details on where you set the labels or the configuration of traefik. [Mcve]

Comment: Ok, updated. I don't use the swarm mode and set the label under the service definition in docker-compose.yml

Comment: Oh, compose scaling, that's completely different. Switch to using swarm mode.

Comment: is it not possible to use compose scaling?